# How to create a list from an existing JSON value?

Tags: python, json

I have an existing json file and want to create a list for a specific field how do I create it? I went through other stackoverflow questions specific to python, but not quite what I was looking for.

Current JSON file:

```
[{"team_name": "Journalist", "team_members": "Ali Smith, Jon Doe"},
{"team_name": "Journalist & Media", "team_members": "A Smith, Micheal P"},
{"team_name": "Photography", "team_members": "Micheal P, Adam A"}]
```

Final output file:

```
[{"team_name": "Journalist", "team_members": ["Ali Smith", "Jon Doe"]},
{"team_name": "Journalist & Media", "team_members": ["A Das", "Micheal P"]},
{"team_name": "Photography", "team_members": ["Micheal P", "Adam A"}]
```

Comment: Other than splitting on ", "?

Comment: `[s.strip() for s in 'this, string, here'.split(',')]`

Comment: from @BrendanAbel comment: Here is how I was able to get it:
```with open('test.json') as json_data:
 data = json.load(json_data) 
 print('All data:', '\n',data)
 print ('')
 for element in data: 
  element['team_members'] = [s.strip() for s in element['team_members'].split(',')]
  print(element)```